# React-native. читать новости из rss. дублирование Fetch. ошибка массива

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, rss

Первый раз пробую писать на данном языке. пишу маленькую приложуху для считывания новостей через rss с сайта. Судя по консоле ловлю такие ошибки. Дублируется вывод запроса rss. Ругается на массив. хотя запрашиваю 1 элемент массива.

```
import * as rssParser from 'react-native-rss-parser';
return fetch('https://kbgau.ru/rss.php')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(rss.items[0].title);
    console.log(rss.items[0].link);
  });
```

При выполнении вышеперечисленные ошибки. Как корректор вывести 1 заголовок в поле Text или хотяб в консоль?

Ошибки :

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Это `{_U, _V, _W, _X}` Promise который еще не выполнился(Resolve-лся) и когда вы делаете `return fetch(...)` вы возвращаете сам Promise, а не результат его выполнения. Для решения лучше всего обернуть его в асинхронную функцию и использовать синтаксис await что бы дождаться пока придёт ответ.

Comment: @Александр Асинхронным понятно, а вот куда ожидание воткнуть? не затруднит ли вас показать правильно работающий код

Comment: как я понимаю его необходимо воткнуть перед rssParser.parse(responseData)), но тогда я ловлю ошибку  'await' is only allowed within async functions (33:26)

Comment: Не совсем вы можете оставить так как есть, если это helper и лежит где-то отдельным файлом. А там где вы вызываете функцию, сделать импорт и там создать функцию типа `const handler = async () => { const result = await importedFetch(); setSomeState(result)}`

Comment: Или если это не helper и находиться в компоненте тогда просто оберните в функцию `const someFunc = async () => {return await fetch(...)}`  и просто вызывайте в компоненте, если есть зависимости для обновления то возможно потребуется обернуть в `useCallback`.

Comment: @Александр Извиняюсь, но один фиг он ругается на массив. Ладно будем разбираться только как пока не знаю